# Application of Zivot-Andrews and Clemente, Montañés, Reyes unit root tests throws error

Tags: stata

I am trying to run the `zandrews` and `clemao` / `clemio` commands in `Stata12`. Unfortunately, I am always given error messages. The data is an artificially created time-series (not a panel data set) to test all unit root tests available for `Stata`. `DFuller` and `Pperron` work without any problems.

I have set the dataset as a time-series (aka used `tsset`), once with a time variable `"Time" = 1, 2, ..., 52`, and then to cross check with another time variable `"YearQuarter" = 2001q1,..., 2013q4`.

When I run `zandrews Var1`, I get the message `"Time/ YearQuarter not found"`. And when I run `clemao1 Var1`, the message says `"invalid syntax"`. To narrow down the problem, I have already used the test datasets provided with each `Stata` code, and those run without problems.

Any ideas why the `zandrews` and `clemao1` / `clemio1` commands do not work?

Data example for clarification:

```
Time    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6    Var7    Var8    Var9
1   10000   10000   10000   10000   10000   10000   10000   10000   406.0469
2   10000   10000   10000   10500   12500   12500   12500   12500   -7.481191
3   10000   10000   10000   11000   10000   10500   10000   10500   826.7238
4   10000   10000   10000   11500   12500   13000   12500   12500   256.6785
5   10000   10000   10000   12000   10000   11000   10000   10000   -523.1082
6   10000   10000   10000   12500   12500   13500   12500   13000   -559.0313
7   10000   10000   10000   13000   10000   11500   10000   10000   75.61687
8   10000   10000   10000   13500   12500   14000   12500   12500   -498.4264
9   10000   10000   10000   14000   10000   12000   10000   10500   610.9489
10  10000   10000   10000   14500   12500   14500   12500   12500   384.8385
11  10000   10000   10000   15000   10000   12500   10000   10000   -1050.993
12  10000   10000   10000   15500   12500   15000   12500   13000   1533.222
13  10000   10000   10000   16000   10000   13000   10000   10000   -629.2033
14  10000   10000   10000   16500   12500   15500   12500   12500   1206.866
15  10000   10000   10000   17000   10000   13500   10000   10500   151.1623
16  10000   10000   10000   17500   12500   16000   12500   12500   -613.176
17  10000   10000   10000   18000   10000   14000   10000   10000   401.4852
18  10000   10000   10000   18500   12500   16500   12500   13000   688.8569
19  10000   10000   10000   19000   10000   14500   10000   10000   288.9656


tsset Time

zandrews Var1

clemao1 Var1
```

Comment: thanks for editing, gung. I am new here

Comment: Thanks for adding a reproducible example. This should be able to be migrated to [SO] now. You will have to wait for it to be migrated, but it shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 0):

`zandrews` is a user-written command from SSC.

It looks like a bug in the program. Running

```
tsset Time
zandrews Var1
```

with `set trace on`, outputs

```
      ----------------------------------------------------------------- end regress ---
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------- end reg ---
  - local b = _b[L.`var']
  = local b = _b[L.Var1]
  - loca se = _se[L.`var']
  = loca se = _se[L.Var1]
  - local tee = `b'/`se'
  = local tee = 0/0
  - qui replace `breakstats'=`tee' in `time'/`time'
  = qui replace __000008=. in 16/16
  - if `tee' < `minbreak'{
  = if . < 10000000000{
    local minbreak = `tee'
    local minent = `time'
    }
  - }
  - local enn = e(N)
  - if "`gen'" != ""{
  = if "" != ""{
    qui replace `gen'=`breakstats' in `tstart'/`tend'
    }
  - local minb = string(`timevar'[`minent'], "`rts'")
  = local minb = string(Time[], "%9.0g")
Time not found
  -------------------------------------------------------------------- end zandrews ---
r(111);
```

The lines

```
- local minb = string(`timevar'[`minent'], "`rts'")
= local minb = string(Time[], "%9.0g")
```

show `local minent` is not defined and the program exits with an error.

I don't use the command and can't advise on how to fix. Contact the author directly. `help zandrews` contains his email address. Please give an update, whatever the case.

### Edit

The `zandrews` and `clem*` routines now give coherent error messages when "there is no variance in the variable being analyzed". (Quote from personal correspondence with the program's author.)

The updated program can be obtained using `adoupdate`. See `help adoupdate`, if in doubt.

### Edit 2

It has further been noticed that in some cases where the series has no unique minimum, it will keep giving the original error, e.g. using `Var7`. The major points here are that the command is not meant to work with "time series" as those presented in the example dataset, and the program's logic does not trap all such cases. Real-world time series usually do not present such behavior.

Nonetheless, a future update with more exhaustive "exception-handling" messages, is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick heads up. I will contact the author and give an update on it.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying, Roberto. Much appreciated